# Cannot Access C Drive to Clear Space for Windows Refresh

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bsod

I have Windows 10, but upon bootup I consistently receive BSOD message SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED.  I cannot actually log in, but I can see a few recovery options.

I am trying to do a system refresh (if someone knows a less drastic fix that can be performed from these recover screens, please let me know).  When I click the option to reset windows but keep my files, it says "Not enough space on the drive where Windows is installed.  Please clear some space and try again."

However, since I cannot log into Windows, I do not know how to clear some space.  Anyone know how I can access my hard drive without being able to boot into Windows?

Thanks,
John

Comment: One way is to remove the hard drive and use a usb to hard drive adapter to connect it to another PC to delete some files to make more space. Another way is to boot from a linux live cd/dvd or usb drive, when linux loads you can delete some files.

Comment: boot a Linux DVD/USb drive and copy the folder C:\Windows\Minidump to an external drive, zip the folder and upload the zip. I'll take a look at it with the debugger